# LOD Workaround with Tableau 8.3

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau. I have a customer-event table to show which customers attended which events (like webinars, etc). One of fields is sales - which is the sales for that customer 30 days from the date of the event.

```
custid   eventid    eventdt   30daysales
1        aa         jan 1        $100
1        ab         jan 1        $100
2        aa         jan 2        $150
```

Note that customer 1 attended 2 events on the same day. So the sales number is duplicated. If I were building a report for a single event, it's no problem. But when I build a monthly report, I want sum(Sales) = $250 and not $350.

My report sample:

```
Month     eventcount     customercount     30daysales
Jan        2               2                $250
```

With tableau 9, I read that using an LOD formula would allow me to sum sales on a per customer basis. But I'm on Tableau 8.3 and I'm wondering what the manual workaround is.

How do I write the calculated field to compute the 30daysales without duplicating?